# how to extract '\+' in string of '\+234' in python3

Tags: python, string, python-3.5, string-literals

I have a string of `str = '\+234'`, from which I would like to create another string of `'\\+'`. And the statement `'\' + str[1]`  gives the following error:

> SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal

But the `str[1]` is `'+'`. Why the two characters cannot be joined?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because "\" is an escaping char.

Try to use double \ instead.

Comment: Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Because `\` is an escape character in python. Try `'\\'+str[1]`